# Are DIY hardware recommendations allowed?

Tags: discussion

Now, I have been interested in the maker and hacker community for a long time. I have learned about the Arduino and Raspberry Pi, etc. Are recommendation questions about such DIY hardware platforms allowed on this website?

For example - "What are some good touchscreens for the Raspberry Pi?" or "What are some good Arduino Wifi boards?"

Comment: I would even go a bit further, are questions asking "what MCU would be better for an application that..." also fitting the scope?

Comment: It may be worth noting, though, that on-topic or not, there is a [Raspberry Pi site](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) and an [Arduino site](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/); users may find they get better answers on those sites, anyways, just because the knowledge base of the community on those sites is specifically geared to those platforms. Of course, I'm not familiar with either of those sites, and I'm not sure how well shopping questions would be received; but many times, shopping questions can be rephrased a bit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't see a reason for them not to be allowed. Your examples would be right in the middle of the electronic hardware space as I see it.

I don't see a reason to limit the site to consumer hardware.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with [Undo](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29/122), would add that you can often find consumer packages for the Pi, Arduino and others (especially as they become more popular).  That would also be a perfectly valid Q&A: i.e. what is a good starter kit for the Raspberry Pi 2, will the case allow for a camera attachment etc.

There's also very little difference between questions like the ones you mentioned and others about building your own HTPC, gaming rig and the like which will certainly be popular and common on this site.